# Android widgets to builld google doc like UI

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I build this android UI? See image. I know - there will not be a standard view/widget, but would like to know android experts - what are the possible ways to build this UI. Is this an image, button, textView or any suggestions on how can I build this?

[image: The file UI in Google docs]

Comment: "how can I build this?" -- what exactly is "this"? I see a `CardView` containing two `TextView` and two `ImageView` widgets at the bottom, overlaying what is either a `WebView` (if that is actual Web content) or an `ImageView` (if it is a thumbnail or something). Your image shows two of those structures.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. Yes, I think CardView will do the job. And correct me - it looks like - the text inside the card view is just a simple text view with small font size.

Comment: Yes, that text seems fairly ordinary, well within the limits of `TextView`.